# Suspend issue in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, suspend

After i put my laptop in suspend mode, screen goes blank as usual. But it remain blank even if i want to recover from suspend mode to normal mode. I have to restart my laptop to make it normal, which is highly irritating.
kindly suggest solution.